# IMS as RESTful WebService Consumer

Tags: rest, web-services, ims-tm

We need to expose IMS as RESTful webservice consumer. I had referred a document  "**Creating a RESTful Web Service for IMS-Transaction**" by **Ivy Ho**, which talks about exposing IMS as RESTful webservice provider. In that document they selected an **OUTBOUND** adapter option while creating an J2C bean(Page Num 4), which makes the data to be passed from application to adapter. Is it possible if I opted **INBOUND** adapter which makes the data to be passed in to the application from the adapter, will it help me to expose IMS as RESTful consumer.

If any proven methods are available, to expose our application as RESTful webservice consumer, kindly share the same ?

Is it possible in the SOAP GATEWAY server to handle REST calls of the client application. So my core application can consume the REST response of client application after the data mapping in the SOAP GATEWAY server.

Kindly share your views and thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The recommended route for your IMS application to consume an external REST service would be through the API Requester function for z/OS Connect EE. The following link provides a step by step guide for doing exactly what you want: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4SVW_3.0.0/com.ibm.zosconnect.doc/scenarios/ims_apiReq_intro.html

The reason this would be recommended is it funnels all outbound calls through a single gateway which can be monitored, modified, and updated without affecting your applications.

Answer (score 2):

SOAP Gateway will not be able to handle REST calls. I suggest looking into IMS Mobile Feature pack which is a restful endpoint for IMS.

IMS Mobile Feature Pack Description:

This feature provides a RESTful endpoint for mobile services to access back-end IMS resources through IMS Connect. A data transformation module is included that converts request and response messages between JSON and the native representation of the input and output messages. Tooling support for modeling, creating, testing, and managing services is provided through IMS Enterprise Suite Explorer for Development.

reference:
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.ims.imsmobile-1.0

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.ims.imsmobile-2.0